# Spring Webflux: spring.main.web-application-type= reactive not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot application that has both spring-web and spring-webflux. Now I am trying to set the web application type to reactive which is not working.
The error I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurationSupport.setApplicationContext(WebFluxConfigurationSupport.java:105)
```

Instead, if I try to set the web application type as Reactive in the below way, it does not work(the webApplicationType is set to SERVLET), though the application starts.

```java
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
app.run(MyApplication.class, args);
```

What can I do to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot have both in the same app, even if it would work make sure you don't have a configuration class with `@EnableWebMvc` (which appears is what you have). Please add your code, configuration and pom.xml to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes i understand. However there is a custom common group and component which we use in our build file. I cannot remove it and not sure where the EnableWebmvc getting used. I have even tried excluding them: exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-webmvc'

Comment: The `@EnableWebMvc` must be somewhere in your own code (or your own custom dependencies) you are using. If that is the case, either exclude that configuration or stop using WebFlux in this application until you can safely use the other custom components with webflux.

Comment: @M.Deinum correct. I found out the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure includes `spring-boot-webflux-starter` in your project dependencies.

Try to use `SpringApplicationBuilder` in your app `main` method to assemble your application resource.

```java
 new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
    .web(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)
    .run(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use thos in application.properties

```
#To specify to use reactive librairies
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```